# Why is running an invalid process with '&' closes the terminal?

Tags: bash

When running, for example, `a&` in bash, the terminal window closes, where I would expect a new process to start followed by an error message (similar to, for example, `grep &`).

What is causing this behavior? Is it intentional?

edit: as requested,

```
yuvalw@UX410UQK:~$ echo $-
himBH
```

I also tried opening another bash in bash to get additional output. My input is `bash` followed by `a&` and a few new lines:

```
yuvalw@UX410UQK:~$ bash
yuvalw@UX410UQK:~$ a&
[1] 15323
yuvalw@UX410UQK:~$ exit
yuvalw@UX410UQK:~$ a: command not found

yuvalw@UX410UQK:~$
```

here calling `a&` again will close the terminal window.

edit2: more echos

```
yuvalw@UX410UQK:~$ echo "$BASH_VERSION $SHELLOPTS $BASHOPTS"
4.3.48(1)-release braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor checkwinsize:cmdhist:complete_fullquote:expand_aliases:extglob:extquote:force_fignore:histappend:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
```

trap:

```
yuvalw@UX410UQK:~$ trap
trap -- '' SIGTSTP
trap -- '' SIGTTIN
trap -- '' SIGTTOU
```

type exit:

```
yuvalw@UX410UQK:~$ type exit
exit is a shell builtin
```

PROMPT_COMMAND (empty):

```
yuvalw@UX410UQK:~$ echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
```

PS1:

```
yuvalw@\UX410UQK:~$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
```

edit 3: Opening a new terminal it doesn't seem like this happens, and I can run `a&` just fine, but after `cd`ing around for a bit the issue returns. In both cases the command_not_found_handle looks the same.

```
yuvalw@yuvalw-UX410UQK:~$ type command_not_found_handle

command_not_found_handle is a function
command_not_found_handle () 
{ 
    if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
        /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1";
        return $?;
    else
        if [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
            /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1";
            return $?;
        else
            printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" 1>&2;
            return 127;
        fi;
    fi
}
```

Comment: I don't get this behaviour at all. I just get the backgrounded pid `[1] 3829`, `bash: a: command not found`, then a new prompt.

Comment: Can you [edit] in the output of `echo $-`?

Comment: @Sparhawk hmm.. Now i'm more puzzled.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Added

Comment: What about the output of `echo "$BASH_VERSION $SHELLOPTS $BASHOPTS"`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Added

Comment: Still can't reproduce with same version, same settings. What about the output of `trap` and `type exit`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas added these as well

Comment: What's in your $PROMPT_COMMAND and $PS1?

Comment: @choroba added.

Comment: What's the output of `type a command_not_found_handle`? That's something I could reproduce with `perl -MPOSIX -e '$SIG{TTOU} = "IGNORE"; tcsetpgrp(1,getpgrp) or die$!' &`. That is with something that puts itself in foreground causing the shell to be in background and then fail to read from the terminal, causing it to exit with that `exit` message.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That was a bug in `bash`, fixed in 4.4.

If you have the `command_not_found_handle()` hook defined (which is invoked when a command is not found), `bash` puts it in foreground even if the *not found command* was started in background.

Then, depending on timing, if the shell reads the command line from the tty device after the `command_not_found_handle` was put in foreground, that `read()` would return with an `EIO` error as happens when a background process reads from a terminal device and ignores the SIGTTIN signal.

`bash` would treat that as *end of file* on user input as if you had pressed <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>

One can reproduce the problem by doing:

```
$ command_not_found_handle() { sleep 20; }
$ a &
$ x
```

Even if the first `read()` succeeds because it's started *before* the `command_not_found_handle` is put in foreground, the second and subsequent reads after you press `x` will fail and cause the shell to exit.

With the default `command_not_found_handle` shipped on Ubuntu,

```
$ a & true &
```

Also causes the shell to exit as the SIGCHLD upon `true` returning interrupts the first `read()` and causes a second one to be started with the handler still running in foreground.

In the general case however, the bug seems unlikely to trigger as the shell also puts itself in foreground before writing its prompt, so the `command_not_found_handle` has to put itself in foreground (do the `tcsetpgrp()`) at the right moment (after the main shell process puts itself in foreground and before it starts reading from the tty device).

That was fixed in April 2015, with [this commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/?id=48abf0fdc980a0bb3f90ca007c6471b083211273) (4/23 entry in CWRU.log) following [a report to a related problem by Valentin Bajrami](https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg16114.html).

Comment: wow, that is a lot more obscure than I thought. Expected it to be something common.. Thank you very much for all the effort, was really informative to me! :)

Comment: @Nescio, it would be interesting to know why you can reproduce it consistently. What's your `command_not_found_handle`? (`type command_not_found_handle`). On which terminal to you see that? Do you see it regardless of which terminal emulator you're using? Are you in a setup where `bash` could end up being a child subreaper (container, systemd...)? What's the OS?

Comment: I added some prints and some additional information to the question itself. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with the default terminal and bash, but honestly I'm pretty new to Linux so I am not sure if this is even a full answer to your question.

Comment: @Nescio. OK thanks, it's some comfort that you can't reproduce consistently. The main reason you can reproduce it more often that others is probably just chance (like your particular hardware puts the timing in that soft spot).